# Can't install .net package due to " supports: net60 (.NETFramework,Version=v6.0)"

Tags: blazor, webassembly, .net-framework-version

I'm trying to install a .net package (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly 6.0.6) which lists .net framework 6.0 and aspnetcore 6.0.6 in dependencies. I have the latest .net 6.0.301 sdk installed and the project target at 6.0, but when building I get the following error.

Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly 6.0.6 is not compatible with netcoreapp6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly 6.0.6 supports: net60 (.NETFramework,Version=v6.0)

I have Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components included and working, just WebAssembly in my WASM app isn't working. Is there some foundational problem with my app being built from .net Core App as opposed to Framework that forever prevents me from installing this package? Apologies as I am struggling to understand .net versioning/packaging.

The whole reason I'm trying to install this package is due to needing BrowserRequestCredentials from the package in order to send cookies in the request in my WASM app so I'm a bit baffled I can't seem to use it in an app built from the default Blazor WASM template project.

What's also confusing is that it appears that .net framework current highest version is 4.8.

For further reference this is using nuget on Rider. If I install the package directly with dotnet package install, it'll add it but dotnet run still throws the same nu error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally fixed it. Spend a lot of time reinstalling .net to try and fix, but didn't work. Noticed that newly built projects would fail after being opened in Rider. Completely reinstalled Rider and now my packages don't break on build. Everything is finally working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

`netcoreapp6.0` isn't a valid [TFM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks); the correct value is `net6.0`. It's surprising that the compiler appears to be parsing this anyway and expressing it as though it's a moniker that it recognises, but is wrong for the project. There is one .net from version 5.0 onwards and the "core" branding has been dropped, it's just .net 6.0 now.

Comment: Thank you. I had assumed they had been combined from the wording on the download site and my project targetframework in the csproj file is "net6.0" so I'm not sure where it's getting that. I wonder if the problem is with nuget itself and rider parsing dependencies